# setting a large http body

Tags: string, http

I am trying to send a http request with a large string Body; however, salesforce complaints about the size of the string, the error as follows:

> caused by: System.StringException: String length exceeds maximum:
>   12000000

The http request as follows:

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://koala.api');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
String payload = 'client_id=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('39494342', 'UTF-8') + '&file=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(getBase64File(), 'UTF-8');
request.setBody(payload);
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);


static String getBase64File() {
    String result;
    //...
    // to some stuff
    //...
    // at this stage the result contains 12 million characters

    return result;
}
```

The method that causes the issue is getBase64File, this method generates a huge string of about 13 million characters. Is there any workaround for this issue so that I can send the payload?

Comment: There's no way around the string exception, that's a Salesforce limitation. What is it that you're trying to send? At 13 million characters, you're around 10 MB of data.

Comment: I am trying to send a 9MB picture.

Comment: base64 makes things take up more characters (1.333x the original, plus up to 2 additional padding bytes). I don't suppose that reducing the dimensions of the image, or compressing it is an option, is it?

Comment: Salesforce does not put and hard limit on Strings it comes from heap size if you can do it asynchronously then you may get some extra heap size.
String size: Strings have no limit on the number of characters they can include. Instead, the heap size limit is used to ensure that your Apex programs don't grow too large.

Comment: Hi @DerekF F I am sending the pictures from salesforce to our servers to reduce the size, because in Salesforce there is no compression system. So reducing the dimensions of the image, or compressing are not an option.

Comment: You could compress the images _before_ uploading them to Salesforce.

Comment: You could modify your workflow so that users _within_ Salesforce are uploading images to your compression server and, when finished, have the compression service make a request _to_ Salesforce to send it into your org.